# How to view command history of another user in Linux?

Tags: linux, administration, command-history

How can I view the command history of another user?

I am an admin on my machine. I can see normal history by viewing `/home/user_name/.bash_history` but I can't see commands of that `user_name` when they were doing `sudo`.

Is there a way to view all command executed by one user?

Comment: Steal his password :) or by social engineering ..If you are not root, and your account is set up in a way that you can't get go/read other user's home/files you are pretty much restricted.

Comment: "I am an admin on my machine."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

On Debian-based operating systems, doing
`tail /var/log/auth.log | grep username`
should give you a user's `sudo` history.  I don't believe there is a way to get a unified command history of a user's normal + sudo commands.

On RHEL-based operating systems, you would need to check `/var/log/secure` instead of `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: Any clue what this would be on a centos system? My Centos 7 machines don't have a `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Try `/var/log/secure` instead.

Comment: Works perfectly! Just put in an edit request on your answer

Answer (score 18):

Just tested the following, and it worked like a charm.

```
sudo vim /home/USER_YOU_WANT_TO_VIEW/.bash_history
```

Comment: S/he's already aware of this command. From the original question: "I can see normal history by viewing /home/user_name/.bash_history but i can't see commands of that "user_name" when they were doing sudo."

Answer (score 4):

use below command

```
sysdig -c spy_users
```

if sysdig **not installed**, install [here](https://www.tecmint.com/sysdig-system-monitoring-and-troubleshooting-tool-for-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

If the user issued a command as in `sudo somecommand`, the command will appear in the system log.

If the user spawned a shell with eg, `sudo -s`, `sudo su`, `sudo sh`, etc, then the command *may* appear in the history of the root user, that is, in `/root/.bash_history` or similar.

Comment: Where is the system log?

Answer (score 1):

`# zless /var/log/auth*` is your friend here. It opens even the gzipped files. You can jump between those with `:n` forwards or `:p` backwards.

Alternatively, you can use `# journalctl -f -l SYSLOG_FACILITY=10` for instance. Read more about this on the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Journal)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link has a value to you
: http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2000-March/000052.html

But you should mind that leaving no trace in bash_history is just a matter of starting a command with a space etcpp. The history is a helper, not a logging-tool.

Greetings from Germany,
Daniel Leschkowski

Answer (score -1):

The logic applies to many other objectives.
And how to read .sh_history of each user from /home/ filesystem? What if there are thousands of them?

```
#!/bin/ksh
last |head -10|awk '{print $1}'|
 while IFS= read -r line
 do
su - "$line" -c 'tail .sh_history'
 done
```

[Here](https://github.com/imvieira/SysAdmin_DevOps_Scripts/blob/master/get_and_run.sh) is the script.